# Can element width/height be less than min-width/min-height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, browser

I have defined `min-width` for div elements (`float:left`). I set their actual width from JavaScript based on window size using `$('div.element').css('width','123')`

This arrangement works well most of the time but breaks when the browser introduces a vertical scroll-bar, resizing the elements to less than min-width.

Can the elements be re-sized to less than `min-width` from JavaScript by changing just their width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be able to change an element's width to less than its specified `min-width` value. Here is a jsfiddle showing how this works, click on the divs to see their width after having it set in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/sPen2/1/

Comment: That jsfiddle script works correctly, and I expected that behaviour.

If not js, could the browser set the width to less than min-width?

Comment: Thanks! Haven't been able to figure out how that width is being set to less than min-width, but been able to find a workaround.

The formula calculating width was earlier based on window.width. Now, I'm using max(window.width and body.min-width) to work around it.

Comment: @AdiB You're welcome. And welcome to the StackOverflow community. If you haven't checked it out I suggest browsing the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq. Also up-votes and accepted-answers are always welcome :).